# Linear system with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a condition on the parameters a,b,c so that this system will have a solution?

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = a$

$x_1 + 6x_2 + 3x_2 = b$

$3x_1 -2x_2 + x_3 = c$

Comment: I suppose a typo in the second equation : $3x_3$ may be !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Gauss elimination you get
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&a\\
1&6&3&b\\
3&-2&1&c
\end{pmatrix} \implies 
 \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&a\\
0&5&2&b-a\\
0&-5&-2&c-3a
\end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&a\\
0&5&2&b-a\\
0&0&0&c+b-4a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So the system has a solution if $\ c+b-4a=0$, otherwise it is inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you take the determinant of the system-representing matrix for the left, it is 0. Why?

Why quickly see that the second and third equation on the left sum to four times the first. Aha! Therefore the desired parameter is $b+c=4a$.

Hope this helps.